# Must you pay Raise Dead component cost when using the Ashen Crown?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-death

The Ashen Crown, an artifact from `Seekers of the Ashen Crown`, reads, in part:

> Power  Daily (Standard Action)
>
> As the ritual Gentle Repose, but no
>   components are required.
>
> Power  Weekly
>
> As the ritual Speak with Dead,
>   with a +5 item bonus to the Religion check.
>
> Power  Monthly
>
> As the
>   ritual Raise Dead, with a performance time of 1 hour instead of 8
>   hours.

But then, if it is  `Pleased`, it adds another power:

> Power  Weekly
>
> With the whole Crown, as the ritual Raise Dead, with the
>   normal component cost and a performance time of 1 hour instead of 8
>   hours.

Obviously, using the weekly Raise Dead power will cost gold. But will using the Crown still expend money, when using Raise Dead only once per month?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would argue that **Yes**, using the Monthly Raise Dead power requires the normal component cost of Raise Dead.

The description of the power says that it works as the ritual Raise Dead, which would mean it inherits all costs that the ritual would normally require *except* that it takes only 1 hour to perform. The daily power that emulates Gentle Repose explicitly states it has no component cost. While the weekly version of the Raise Dead power explicitly mentions the cost is required, omitting this doesn't imply no component cost, as the daily power seems to imply that component costs are still required unless stated. The weekly version of the power is also defined in another section below the statblock of the Ashen Crown, which would explain the variation in phrasing (as it's no longer implied that component costs are included).

Comment: Powers/rules in 4e do precisely what they say they do, no more, no less, with no exceptions. It doesn't say that it modifies the component costs, so it does not modify the component costs.